# Do an assembly have multiple namespaces or is composed of single namespace

Tags: dll, assemblies, namespaces

Can an assemble have multiple namespaces or is composed of single namespace.

Comment: Are you asking if you can define multiple namespaces in an assembly?

Comment: @Ando Yeh I mean to ask this: can a single assembly contain multiple namespaces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- An assemblies is a collection of code - objects, methods, properties, and other resources.
- A Namespace is a logical groupings of those things.

An assembly can contain multiple namespaces, because it can contain multiple logical groupings of objects and methods. Most assemblies I've seen are a single namespace, just for clarity, but there's no reason a single assembly couldn't contain a dozen different namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

The hierarchy is:
`Assemblies` contain `Resources` and `Modules`.

`Modules` contain `Fields`,`Methods`, and `Types`.

`Types` may be qualified by any arbitrary namespace, provided that it doesn't conflict with another existing `Type`.

Assemblies can short circuit past the Module level directly to all Types contained in all Modules in the assembly (via GetType() or GetTypes()).

Answer (score 1):

Assemblies can have multiple namespaces.

Comment: How ? What is the logic behind that. What process goes on behind this.

Comment: @sha: An assembly is a different grouping concept than a namespace. They have different purposes and are not linked.

Comment: @Johan: Could you please provide some refrence supporting your answer so that some gud knowledge can be obtained about their creation

Comment: For example, in C#, the System namespace, as well as the System.IO and a whole other set of namespaces are contained in the System.Core.dll file.

http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/systemcoredll.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Please see the msdn article *[Understanding and Using Assemblies and Namespaces in .net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973231.aspx)*, that should clear up what does *assembly* mean and what does *namespace* mean.